# View output of a script using screen

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run multiple scripts in detached screen sessions at the same time.

This is the code I currently have.

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -mdS Name_Screen1 "python /path/to/file/file.py arg1 arg2 arg3"
screen -mdS Name_Screen2 "python /path/to/file/file.py arg3 arg4 arg5"
screen -mdS Name_Screen3 "python /path/to/file/file.py arg6 arg7 arg8"
```

When typing "screen -list" to see what screens are available, I don't see any of the screens I'm currently running. This scripts outputs some information to the screen, which depends on the arguments given. I've looked through some of the problems posted in here, but I can't find an answer for this.

Is there any way I can look at the outputs of these screens without having to do something like "> out.txt"?

**Update**

So I finally figured it out. I ended up creating just one screen session and multiple windows within the session.

```
#!/bin/sh
Lum_Types=("Window1" "Window2" "Window3" )
Windowname="Screen_session"
screen -mdS $Windowname
for Lum in ${Lum_Types[@]}
do
    screen -S $Windowname -X screen -t $Lum
    screen -S $Windowname -p $Lum -X stuff $"python /Path/to/file arg1 arg2"
    screen -S $Windowname -p $Lum -X stuff $'\n'
done
```

One key part was to add the `$` after the `-X stuff` in order to pass the string to the screen session and windows.

Comment: You don't see those screens as running? Are you running `screen -list` as the same user? Are those processes still running or have they exited?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, I'm running screen -list as the same user. If I do "screen -mdS Name_Screen" command first without the rest of the command, then the screen is created. But for some reason, when I attach the rest of the command, nothing appears.

Comment: Do the processes end before you check? What do those processes do? Can you run them in screen correctly manually?

Comment: @EtanReisner No, the processes take about ~ 1 hour to complete each, so they shouldn't end before that. If I run them manually inside a screen session, they work fine. The scripts print some statements to the screen, which if I'm attached to the screen, I'm able to see. Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Do they work if you run `screen "python /path/to/file/file.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` from within a screen session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. I ended up creating just one screen session and multiple windows within the session.

```
#!/bin/sh
Lum_Types=("Window1" "Window2" "Window3" )
Windowname="Screen_session"
screen -mdS $Windowname
for Lum in ${Lum_Types[@]}
do
    screen -S $Windowname -X screen -t $Lum
    screen -S $Windowname -p $Lum -X stuff $"python /Path/to/file arg1 arg2"
    screen -S $Windowname -p $Lum -X stuff $'\n'
done
```

One key part was to add the `$` after the `-X stuff` in order to pass the string to the screen session and windows.

– Victor

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is separate the words of the command.

```
screen -mdS "Name_Screen1" python /path/to/file/file.py "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
```

with them grouped in a sngle strin screen won't execute them, it just quits straight away,
that's why they don't show in the list.